# PostgreSQL not working after creating a symbolic link on the pg_hba.conf file

Tags: symlink, postgresql

I'm trying to create a symbolic link on `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` (default path on Fedora) pointing to the real file located somewhere else, for example `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf -> /home/pg_hba.conf` (command for this example: `sudo ln -sf /home/pg_hba.conf /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`).

I set `/home/pg_hba.conf` permissions (`-rw-------`), owner (`postgres`) and group (`postgres`) to be just like the original `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` file, I even tried to `chmod 777`. When I switch to user `postgres` and I `cat /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` (which is now a symlink) it successfully prints the content of the `/home/pg_hba.conf` file.

However when I try to apply the changes by doing `sudo systemctl restart postgresql` I get the following error

> Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
>
> See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xeu postgresql.service" for details.

I checked the logs but there's no other useful information.

It's only working when I point my symlink to a file in the same directory (`/var/lib/pgsql/data/`) which is totally useless (ex: `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf -> /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf.bak`)

If I point to anywhere else it doesn't work, even in `/var/lib/pgsql` which is actually the Home directory of the `postgres` user!

I'm new to Linux so I tried to create a symbolic link with my `~/.bashrc` file just for the sake of trying (ex: `~./bashrc -> /home/.bashrc`) I wrote an `echo "TEST!"` inside this file and applied the new configuration with `. ~/.bashrc` and it works just fine, my `TEST!` is successfully printed out.

So what's the deal with PostgreSQL?
How can I fix this error and keep a symbolic link on the `pg_hba.conf` file?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Why do you need to do that anyway?

Comment: @NasirRiley Every time I install PostgreSQL on a new PC I have to remember to change this effing file  so I can finally login with the `postgres` user and set a new password. So annoying, I want to save this file in a git repository like a regular dotfile

Comment: I don't know what PostgreSQL or OS you are using but login is usually possible from the local system right after the database is initialized and the service started without any need to edit any of the config files.

Comment: @NasirRiley I'm a Fedora. Yes it's possible to log in a shell using the `sudo su - postgres` command (the only way to log in actually) but it's *not* possible to log in from a database tool such as [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io) or with any programming language using a connection string, which is exactly what I want to do 100% of the times. The only way to unlock this is to modify the `pg_hba.conf` file and change *IPv4 local connections's method* from `ident` to `md5`

Comment: Anyway, IMO there's no point discussing whether or not I need or don't need to do that. The thing is, I **want** to do that and to my understanding, a symlink should behave exactly like if the real file was directly located in this directory as long as I set the right permissions on the target file and all its parent directories (which I did). I take this challenge as a good opportunity to improve my skills and knowledge in Linux.

Comment: You don't need to log into a shell as the `postgres` user to set the password. That can be done afterwards from the console via `psql -u postgres` and has to be done anyway regardless of the contents of `pg_hba`. For what it's worth, I was able to do what you are trying to do with no issue so there is something that you are doing differently. In any event, if you want to improve your skills, then it's best to consider the advice of someone who has been working with it for a much longer time. What you are trying to do isn't needed at all and as you can see, is only complicating things.

Comment: Also, while this isn't anything personal, I suggest doing more research on how PostgreSQL functions. If you just want to be able to connect to it from a tool with certain users, then you can edit the `pg_hba.conf` file afterwards which you'll have to do anyway. That's far easier than what you are trying to do and you'd still have to set passwords for the user(s).

Comment: I tried your `psql -U postgres` command (with an uppercase `U` because lowercase isn't a valid option) and I get `Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`. If you managed to get it working with a symlink why don't you just post an answer instead of keeping trying to convince me that what I want to achieve is wrong? Show me how you managed to do it in Fedora and I'd be glad to accept your answer. So far your comments didn't help me at all...

Comment: One year from now, will I remember which file I have to modify in order to be able to connect to PostgreSQL? Absolutely *not*! Do I want to Google again and again every single modification I made to setup my working environment as I want it? It's a big *NO*. I already created several symlinks and I'm planning to do this for every single configuration file I modify. Besides automatizing the process (because I'm a lazy developer), this git repository will become my own personal Wiki.

Comment: The `-u` was a typo on my part as I was posting at after 3 in the morning. The file that you modify is the same: `pg_hba.conf` in the data directory and then you restart the service. As far as how I did it, I used the same method that is mentioned in every guide on the internet: Install postgresql-server, initialize the database, and start the service. Afterwards, `psql -U postgres` opens the console. If you were to read those guides, then they'd give you everything that you need. None of them mention creating symlinks to the config files because it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: You don't need to Google what to do. After you've done it enough times, it'll become second nature unless you have a terrible memory. If there are many config files that you to always be the same without having to manually edit them, then you are better off using configuration management software such as Puppet or Ansible. As it stands right now, you are still doing it manually which defeats the purpose and you are creating a mess of symlinks that you need to keep track of. If that's what you want to do, then you're on your own. None of this is rocket science.

Comment: You're still talking that I'm doing something wrong even though I already told you there's no point of arguing, I just **want** to understand what's going on and how to fix it. What's wrong with wanting to understand things? But I get it, you just want to have the last word so I'm done wasting my time with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after more research about this issue, turns out the root cause comes from [SELinux](https://linux.die.net/man/8/postgresql_selinux).

I managed to get it working by completely disabling SELinux (obviously not recommended)

```bash
/usr/bin/setenforce Permissive
```

I've also tried with `chcon` and `semanage` ([documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files)) but without any success

```bash
chcon -R -t postgresql_db_t /home
semanage fcontext -a -t postgresql_db_t /home
```

If anybody knows how to do this without completely disabling SELinux I'd be really interested to know.

Obviously fighting against SELinux is not the way to go so I'm giving up what I was trying to achieve but that was very interesting to learn (I've never heard of SELinux before). Even if my answer is just explaining the root cause without giving the fix, I think this is much more constructive than a *"trust me bro, don't do this"*...